# iOS app uploaded via iTunes Connect "has one or more issues"

Tags: ios, cordova, info.plist

I've scoured the web for a working solution to this and tried them all with no success. I'm hoping that if I'm specific somebody can help.

I use Adobe PhoneGap to package up my HTML5,CSS,JS game.
I download the .ipa file and upload via Application Loader on Mac.

The error returned is: 
Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

So I looked at PhoneGap's own recommendation at http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/
and added the following to my own config.xml

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
    <array>
        <string>Does not use photo library</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

I bumped the version number in the config.xml, packaged it up for PhoneGap, downloaded the .ipa and re-uploaded via ApplicationLoader.
I get the same error.

I'd assumed from the documentation that this was how we get information into the otherwise inaccessible info.plist

I'd be hugely grateful for a solution to this.

Many thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Are you using camera and photo library in your application?

Comment: Hi Yogendra, no I'm not using the camera or photo library.

Comment: you are not using camera and photo library. have you need <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
    <array>
        <string>Does not use photo library</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file> 
in config.xml???

Comment: Any way you can try to my answer and it may be work. bc according to your error --> need to add Camera and PhotoLibrary permission in iOS project info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is not array. Its string value.

```
  <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
    <string>App is using Photolibrary</string>
  </gap:config-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add Camera and PhotoLibrary permission in iOS project `info.plist`** check this link : [add permission iOS .plist](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Message</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Message</string>
```

Comment: This is my problem. Using PhoneGap I don't have direct access to the info.plist file. The only option I appear to have is to amend the config file. PhoneGap then creates the info.plist for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should add the description of permissions in info.plist as the following.

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Message</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Message</string>

Otherwise your app will crashes.

You don't use any private frameworks in your app.

Try to validate your build through xcode, It gives the exact errors in the build.
```